# How to load modal dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Hello I am wondering how can I load a modal dynamically on different images. This is my current webpage.

[image]

Suppose when I click the life of pi image this is the modal that pops up.

[image]

I want the same thing to occur with the other images. Suppose If I click on the Kite Runner image it opens a modal with the kite runner image on the left and the text on the right.

This is my current code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var $modal = $("#myModal");
      $("#lifeofpi").click(function() {
        $modal.show();
      });
      $modal.find('.close').click(function() {
        $modal.hide();
      });
    });
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: auto;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 700px;
height: 500px;
background-color: #101010;

}


/* The Close Button */
.close {
color: #aaaaaa;
float: right;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

  

.modallifeofpi {
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 160px; // height
 //width: 30%; // width
 border: 5px solid white;
 display: inline;
 margin-top:0px;
 position: absolute;
 }


 .modalheader {
 color:white;
 margin:0;
 margin-left: 470px;

 }

 .modalheadertext {
 color:white;
 margin-left: 350px;
 margin-top:40px;
 }
  
 .review-img {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 160px; // height
  //width: 30%; // width
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class='images'>
<img class="review-img" id="lifeofpi" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51atapp7YTL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="lifeofpi"></img>
<img class="review-img" id="kiterunner" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51MtGFNeYjL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="kiterunner"></img> </img>
<img class="review-img" id="starwars" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51oqkfvEwZL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="starwars"></img>
<img class="review-img" id="twilight" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41K99+cInvL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="twilight"></img>
</section>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
   <!-- Modal content -->
   <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>

  <img class="modallifeofpi" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51atapp7YTL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="lifeofpi"></img>
  <h1 class="modalheader">Life of pi</h1>
  <h2 class="modalheadertext">Published:</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to add `jQuery` in snippet

Comment: Sorry I am not sure why the snippet isnt working how it appears on my webpage. and I did add jquery in snippet

Comment: Do you have an external source where you are getting the modals information from or are you just putting the information on the page with the images?

Comment: Try to use fancybox !

Comment: I linked it to jquery

Comment: I mean were are you getting the modals information from like the text that is going along side the image in the modal are you just placing it on the page or do you have a json file or text file that you are retrieving the information from or are you planning on just putting the information on the page?

Comment: It basically works now I just have to chance the size of the modal

Comment: @cars, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just bind all images and pass the images information to modal.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var $modal = $("#myModal");
      $(".images img").click(function() {
    $modal.find('img.modallifeofpi').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
    $modal.find('.modalheader').text($(this).attr('alt'));
    $modal.show();
});
$modal.find('.close').click(function() {
    $modal.hide();
});
    });
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: auto;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 700px;
height: 500px;
background-color: #101010;

}


/* The Close Button */
.close {
color: #aaaaaa;
float: right;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

  

.modallifeofpi {
 width: 300px;
 height: 450px;
 border: 5px solid white;
 display: inline;
 margin-top:0px;
 position: absolute;
 }


 .modalheader {
 color:white;
 margin:0;
 margin-left: 470px;

 }

 .modalheadertext {
 color:white;
 margin-left: 350px;
 margin-top:40px;
 }
  
 .review-img {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 160px; // height
  //width: 30%; // width
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class='images'>
<img class="review-img" id="lifeofpi" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51atapp7YTL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="lifeofpi"></img>
<img class="review-img" id="kiterunner" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51MtGFNeYjL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="kiterunner"></img> </img>
<img class="review-img" id="starwars" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51oqkfvEwZL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="starwars"></img>
<img class="review-img" id="twilight" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41K99+cInvL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="twilight"></img>
</section>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
   <!-- Modal content -->
   <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>

  <img class="modallifeofpi" src="./images/lifeofpi.jpg"></img>
  <h1 class="modalheader">Life of pi</h1>
  <h2 class="modalheadertext">Published:</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code works thanks but If I wanted to add different information such as about the book on each modal how would I do it. By information I mean like a paragraph.

Comment: then you can create div for each image section and add paragraph there. Going send you an example soon.

Comment: @cars, here is the example you are seeking: https://jsfiddle.net/ruhul105/x9bvLwjL/15/

Comment: Rahul Amin If I wanted to load the modal content by Ajax do you know how I would do it. using the .load function

Answer (score 0):

Use class as selector and set image sources as an attr on the images. Also you can fill the other fields by this way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $modal = $("#myModal");
    $(".modal-img").click(function() {
        $modal.find('img.modallifeofpi').attr('src',$(this).attr('img-src'));
        $modal.find('.modalheader').text($(this).attr('img-title'));
        $modal.show();
    });
    $modal.find('.close').click(function() {
        $modal.hide();
    });
});
```

and HTML :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class='images'>
<img class="review-img modal-img" id="lifeofpi" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51atapp7YTL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" img-title="Life of pi" img-src="./images/lifeofpi.jpg" alt="lifeofpi"></img>
<img class="review-img modal-img" id="kiterunner" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51MtGFNeYjL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" img-title="Kite Runner" img-src="./images/kiterunner.jpg" alt="kiterunner"></img> </img>
<img class="review-img modal-img" id="starwars" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51oqkfvEwZL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" img-title="Star Wars" img-src="./images/starwars.jpg" alt="starwars"></img>
<img class="review-img modal-img" id="twilight" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41K99+cInvL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" img-title="Twinlight" img-src="./images/twinlight.jpg" alt="twilight"></img>
</section>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>

  <img class="modallifeofpi" src=""></img>
  <h1 class="modalheader">Life of pi</h1>
  <h2 class="modalheadertext">Published:</h2>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code doesnt work it doesnt even make the first image modal appear

Comment: @cars I did not give you a fish. I just tried to teach you that "how you can catch a fish" but you have not gotten it

Answer (score 0):

Assign the attributes of `img` to modal and then display the modal. Check below example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $modal = $("#myModal");
  var src = "";

  $('.images img').click(function() {
    $img = $(this);
    $modal.find('img').attr('src', $img.attr('src'));
    $modal.find('.modalheader').text($img.attr('alt'));
    $modal.show();
  });


  $('#myModal .close').click(function() {
    $modal.hide();
  });
});
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #101010;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.review-img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modallifeofpi {
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

.modalheader {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 470px;
}

.modalheadertext {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 350px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class='images'>
  <img class="review-img" id="lifeofpi" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51atapp7YTL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="lifeofpi" />
  <img class="review-img" id="kiterunner" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51MtGFNeYjL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="kiterunner" />
  <img class="review-img" id="starwars" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51oqkfvEwZL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="starwars" />
  <img class="review-img" id="twilight" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41K99+cInvL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="twilight" />
</section>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img class="modallifeofpi" src="./images/lifeofpi.jpg" />
    <h1 class="modalheader">Life of pi</h1>
    <h2 class="modalheadertext">Published:</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```